# QgsComposerMap does not fit extent

Tags: qgis, printing, pdf, rendering

How can I fit the map extent into the `QgsComposerMap` size?

```py
printable_layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
printable_layers_ids = []
bigger_printable_layer = None

for layer in printable_layers:
    printable_layers_ids.append(layer.id())

    if type(bigger_printable_layer) != type(None):
        if layer.extent().width() + layer.extent().height() > bigger_printable_layer.extent().width() + bigger_printable_layer.extent().height():
            bigger_printable_layer = layer
    else:
        bigger_printable_layer = layer

printable_layers_ids.reverse()

template_document = QtXml.QDomDocument()
template_document.setContent(QtCore.QFile(Printer.printing_template_file_path), False)

map_renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
map_renderer.setLayerSet(printable_layers_ids)

rect = QgsRectangle(map_renderer.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
map_renderer.setExtent(rect)

map_renderer.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 600), 300)

composition = QgsComposition(map_renderer)
composition.loadFromTemplate(template_document)

composer_map = QgsComposerMap(composition, 0, 0, composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight())
composer_map.setNewExtent(rect)
composer_map.updateItem()
composition.addComposerMap(composer_map)

# add created map to composition layers list
composition.refreshZList()

# not working
# composition.moveItemToBottom(composer_map)
# must do that instead
composition.setAllUnselected()
composition.setSelectedItem(composer_map)
composition.moveSelectedItemsToBottom()

# must refresh
composition.refreshZList()
composition.refreshItems()

composition.exportAsPDF(printed_file_path + ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 2):

Done

```py
map_renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
map_renderer.setLayerSet(printable_layers_ids)

composition = QgsComposition(map_renderer)
composition.loadFromTemplate(template_document)

map_renderer.setOutputSize(QSize(composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight()), composition.printResolution())
map_renderer.setExtent(bigger_printable_layer.extent())

composer_map = QgsComposerMap(composition, 0, 0, composition.paperWidth(), composition.paperHeight())
composer_map.setNewExtent(map_renderer.extent())
composition.addComposerMap(composer_map)
```